# How to upgrade agent for better CPU

Tags: azure-devops

I'm running a Cypress test in my build pipeline (vmImage: ubuntu-latest) and it exports a video of the test. But the video freezes after 3 seconds (while the video itself is 15 seconds long). Locally the video runs fine. It seems this is an issue when creating the video on a low-end CPU.

I've disabled encoding for the video so it takes less CPU:

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "cypress/integration/",
  "reporter": "junit",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "tests/test-output-[hash].xml",
    "toConsole": false,
    "attachments": true
  },
  "video": true,
  "videoCompression": false,
  "videosFolder": "tests/video",
  "pluginsFile": "cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.js",
  "viewportWidth": 1600,
  "viewportHeight": 1280
}
```

Is it possible to upgrade the agent I'm running the build pipeline on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The hosted agents all run on the same VM type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#hardware) (today: Standard_DS2_v2)

If you need bigger VMs for your agents, you can deploy [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to upgrade the agent I'm running the build pipeline on?

I am afraid this is impossible to upgrade the agent for better CPU.

That because the performance of the hosted agents is fixed to the VM tier Microsoft chooses for agents in the pool.

There is a user voice about it [Give us the ability to pay for faster hosted build agents with more CPU and IOPS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/give-us-the-ability-to-pay-for-faster-hosted-build/579577).

And the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations):

> If Microsoft-hosted agents don't meet your needs, then you can deploy
> your own self-hosted agents or use scale set agents.

Scale set agents allows you to specify any custom configuration of agents that will be deployed into your own Azure subscription. Please consider this option if you need VMs with more CPUs or memory, or VMs with custom hardware like GPUs.